# Differentiate between tap, flick and move

Tags: javascript

I'm having difficulty to differentiate between 3 actions: tap, flick and move

- Click = touch + release
- Flick = touch + move + release while still moving
- Move = touch + move + release after stop

The following example works fine with touch screen emulation, however when tested on phone, it only detects "move" action:
https://kf7w27.csb.app/

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box");
let touchData = {};

box.addEventListener("touchstart", e =>
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    const touch = e.changedTouches[0];
    const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    touchData = {start: touch};
    touchData.offsetX = touch.clientX - rect.x;
    touchData.offsetY = touch.clientY - rect.y;
});

box.addEventListener("touchmove", e =>
{
    const touch = e.changedTouches[0];
    box.style.top = touch.clientY - touchData.offsetY + "px";
    box.style.left = touch.clientX - touchData.offsetX + "px";
    touchData.move = touch;
});

box.addEventListener("touchend", e =>
{
    const touch = e.changedTouches[0];
    let result = "clicked";
    if (touchData.move)
    {
        result = "moved";
        if (touchData.move.clientY != touch.clientY ||
            touchData.move.clientX != touch.clientX)
            result = "flicked";
    }
    box.textContent = result;
});
```

```css
#box
{
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  line-height: 10em;
  background-color: #5ca9f0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">tap/flick/move me</div>
```

Any tips how to fix this?

Comment: The difference between a move and a flick is the velocity of the touch when ending. Just comparing whether the last `touchmove` event had the same coordinates as the `touchend` event is not enough - you need to look at multiple move events, with their timestamps, and check whether the average speed towards the end of the touch is above a certain threshold.

Comment: @Bergi that makes sense. is there any kind of "standard" formula for this?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm using this crude method that calculates distance and velocity:

https://cezcss.csb.app/

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box"),
  touchHandler = {
    clickDistance: 3, //maximum distance to consider as a click
    clickVelocity: 0.5, //maximum velocity
    flickDistance: 10, //minimum distance
    flickVelocity: 2.5, //minimum velocity
    maxHistory: 50, //max number of history moves to track
    distance: (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
      const y = x2 - x1;
      const x = y2 - y1;

      return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    },
    historyAdd: (d) => {
      const that = touchHandler;
      that.history.unshift(d);
      if (that.history.length > that.maxHistory)
        that.history.length = that.maxHistory;
    },
    onStart: (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      const that = touchHandler;
      const touch = e.changedTouches[0];
      const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      that.offsetX = touch.clientX - rect.x;
      that.offsetY = touch.clientY - rect.y;
      that.history = [e];
      box.addEventListener("touchmove", that.onMove);
      box.addEventListener("touchend", that.onEnd);
      box.addEventListener("touchcancel", that.onCancel);
    },
    onMove: (e) => {
      const that = touchHandler;
      const touch = e.changedTouches[0];
      box.style.top = touch.clientY - that.offsetY + "px";
      box.style.left = touch.clientX - that.offsetX + "px";
      that.history.unshift(e);
      if (that.history.length > that.maxHistory)
        that.history.length = that.maxHistory;
    },
    onEnd: (e) => {
      const that = touchHandler;
      that.history.unshift(e);
      if (that.history.length > that.maxHistory)
        that.history.length = that.maxHistory;
      const firstMove = that.history[that.history.length - 1],
        { clientX, clientY } = e.changedTouches[0],
        firstX = firstMove ? firstMove.changedTouches[0].clientX : 0,
        firstY = firstMove ? firstMove.changedTouches[0].clientY : 0,
        distance = that.distance(clientX, clientY, firstX, firstY),
        velocity =
          that.history.length < 2
            ? 0
            : distance / (e.timeStamp - firstMove.timeStamp),
        isClicked =
          distance < that.clickDistance && velocity < that.clickVelocity,
        isFlicked =
          distance > that.flickDistance && velocity >= that.flickVelocity,
        isMoved = !isClicked && !isFlicked;

      let result = "clicked";

      if (isFlicked) result = "flicked";
      else if (isMoved) result = "moved";

      box.textContent =
        result +
        "\ndistance: " +
        distance.toFixed(2) +
        "\nvelocity: " +
        velocity.toFixed(2) +
        "\nhistory:" +
        that.history.length;
      that.onCancel(e);
    },
    onCancel: (e) => {
      box.removeEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler.onMove);
      box.removeEventListener("touchend", touchHandler.onEnd);
      box.removeEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler.onCancel);
    }
  };

box.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler.onStart);
```

```css
#box {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background-color: #5ca9f0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Click/flick/move me</div>
```